# How to re-enable startup applicaiton to a standard account user from administrator account

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-accounts

I disabled almost all startup applications in a standard account from task manager including one named "program" and the account is unable to login(it auto logs out). Is there a way to re-enable them if I have access to administrator account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I disabled almost all startup applications in a standard account from
> task manager including one named "program" and the account is unable
> to login(it auto logs out). Is there a way to re-enable them if I have
> access to administrator account?

Log into the Administrator's Account and re-enable the Startup Applications.

Re-enable them for the Standard User, or, if the does not work, enable of All Users. This may mean adding a Shortcut to the All Users startup folder.

You many need to remove the app from the Startup folder for the Standard User.

You may need to experiment a bit to see what works best.

=====

If you run into a lot of difficulty, you can make a new User Profile and Account for the User and recover the documents (email) they need from the old profile.

**Follow up:**  The startup App "program" in Task Manager does not have any properties.

Accordingly you will not be able to fix this particular app in the startup folder, and I think you need "program" for the user to be able to start.

So likely you will need to create a new User Profile and Account for this user.

=====

Comment: How do you re-enable them for standard user?

Comment: Look in the Startup folder for the standard user and see if shortcuts are there. As I said you may have to experiment a bit

Comment: I had some time to look and "program" in the startup tab of Task Manager has no properties and may not have a startup shortcut. So you may have to make a new profile. I amended my answer